# Datatables Laravel loop in ajax call using yajrabox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, datatables

```
 function setDataTableTgl(tgl = null, tglA = null, tglB = null, departemenId = null, group = true){
      setColumn(group);
      var tgl = {};
for (var i=1; i < 32; i++) {             
        tgl[i] = i; 
      };
      $('.tableCustom3').DataTable().destroy();
      $('.tableCustom3').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        bPaginate: false,
        ajax: {
          url: "{{ route('scoreboard.index') }}",
          type: "GET",
          data: {
            tglA: tglA,
            tglB: tglB,
            departemenId: departemenId,
            group: group,
            tgl: tgl
          }
        },
        columns: [
          { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex' },
          { data: 'cabang', name: 'cabang' },
          { data: 'score', name: 'score' },
          { data: 'action', name: 'action' },
          { data: 'Day 1', name: 'Day 1' },
          { data: 'Day 2', name: 'Day 2' },
          { data: 'Day 3', name: 'Day 3' },
          { data: 'Day 4', name: 'Day 4' },
//i want this data to continue until Day 31
        ]
      });
    }
```

how to add the column that long with for ? or do i just have to manual it and also like to ask about the `tgl: tgl` i pass the tgl data as array would it work ?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what you are asking - but... (1) "_add the column that long with for_" - Sure - create a variable before you create the DataTable (`myColsArrayData = [];`). That array can contain objects generated by a `for` loop. Use that variable in the DataTable: `columns: myColsArrayData`; (2) "_pass the tgl data as array would it work ?_" Sure - why not just try it? And then my question to you is: Did it work? If not, show your attempts for both items (1) and (2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- pass tgl data using **JSON.stringify(array)** function.

  ```
  ajax: {
             url: "{{ route('scoreboard.index') }}",
             type: "GET",
             data: {
               tglA: tglA,
               tglB: tglB,
               departemenId: departemenId,
               group: group,
               tgl: JSON.stringify(tgl)
             }
           },
  ```